# grep caret appears to have no effect

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I was under the impression that a caret symbol means "*beginning of the line*" with Extended POSIX regular expressions.

However, when I use it with `grep` it behaves unexpectedly.

I am using *GNU* `grep` *2.5.4* on *Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx*.

I echo out a line ' *hello*', then pipe it to a `grep` that searches for "*zero-or-more white-space characters followed by the letter **h***":

```
echo ' hello' | grep -E '[:space:]*h'
hello
```

`grep` finds it ok.

If I add a caret to indicate that I only want the pattern to match "*zero-or-more white-space characters followed by the letter **h** at the beginning of the string*":

```
echo ' hello' | grep -E '^[:space:]*h'
```

No matches are found. I would expect the string to have matched because it begins with *white-space* followed by **h**.

Why does this caret symbol prevent a match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find a space, you have to use `[:space:]` inside another pair of brackets, which will look like `[[:space:]]`. You probably meant to express `grep -E '^[[:space:]]*h'`

To explain why your current one fails:

As it stands, `[:space:]*h` includes a character class looking for any of the characters: `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, and `e` which occur any number of times (including 0), followed by `h`. This matches your string just fine, but if you run `grep -o`, you'll find that you've only matched the `h`, not the space.

If you add a carat to the beginning, either one of those letters or `h` must be at the beginning of the string to match, but none are, so it does not match.

Comment: Aaahaa. This makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it assumes that `[:space:]` will only appear within a bracket expression (highlighted matches with *):

```
echo 'hello' | grep -E '^[:space:]*h'
*h*ello
echo 'hello' | grep -E '[^[:space:]]*h'
*h*ello
echo ' hello' | grep -E '^[[:space:]]*h'
* h*ello
```

This is explained by the following snippet from `man grep` (my highlighting):

> Finally,  certain  named  classes  of  characters are predefined **within bracket expressions** [...] Note that the brackets in these class names are part of the symbolic names, and **must be included in addition to the brackets** delimiting the bracket expression.

Comment: Yes. I think that's correct. I have just noticed the man "(Note that the brackets in these [predefined] class names are part of the symbolic names, and must be included in addition  to  the  brackets  delimiting  the  bracket expression.)"